# MySQL Foreign keys and tables not being created with errno 105

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm trying to add some tables to a database using the following SQL, problem is It's creating the first table, but throwing an error:

```
[Err] 1005 - Can't create table 'BigBlockStudios_woodcraft.sbb_categories' (errno: 150)
```

when I try to run it.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `sbb_catalog`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sbb_catalog`;
CREATE TABLE `sbb_catalog` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sku` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `category` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `make` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `model` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX (`category`,`type`,`make`,`model`,`year`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`category`) REFERENCES sbb_categories(`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES sbb_type(`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  FOREIGN KEY (`make`) REFERENCES sbb_make(`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  FOREIGN KEY (`model`) REFERENCES sbb_model(`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  FOREIGN KEY (`year`) REFERENCES sbb_year(`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `sbb_categories`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sbb_categories`;
CREATE TABLE `sbb_categories` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `sbb_makes`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sbb_makes`;
CREATE TABLE `sbb_makes` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `make` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `sbb_models`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sbb_models`;
CREATE TABLE `sbb_models` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `model` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `sbb_vehicle_types`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sbb_vehicle_types`;
CREATE TABLE `sbb_vehicle_types` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `sbb_years`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sbb_years`;
CREATE TABLE `sbb_years` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `year` decimal(4,0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

First time I've tried to create innodb tables with the build in relations [trying to learn some YII]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe make category unsigned, too?

Comment: You have a couple of unsigned missing and you reference a table which is missing(sbb_type),also the table order is wrong you are creating foreign keys to tables which are yet to be created ,also you reference table names in their singular http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/689104

Comment: SQL Fiddle produces an error on the first table, because the foreign key reference tables are not defined.  There could be all manner of problems when using `drop table if exists` and you have existing tables with the wrong structure.

Comment: The `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` should remove the need for the correct order. @Mihai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the reason is due to a data type mismatch between the column `id` in `sbb_categories` and `category` in `sbb_catalog`. Remove`unsigned`from the former or add it to the latter. **The same goes for all other of your foreign key references.**

As @Mihai pointed out in a comment you also have names that don't match - this obviously needs to be changed so for example:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES sbb_type(`id`)
```

should be changed to

```
FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES sbb_types(`id`)
```

Making these changes makes it work (at least in [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/821a2))

Comment: Thanks! yes , it did seem to be a combination of those things.